# How to group daily data into months in a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing daily counts of number group members seen present. I am wanting to get a monthly mean of the number of group members seen (produced in a data frame). I've been trying to use dplyr as it is much simpler than creating a new data frame and filling it using a for loop. I'm very new to coding and would like to be able to do this for multiple groups. My dataframe looks like this:

```
data.frame':    148 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Date                     : Date, format: "2013-05-01" "2013-05-02" ...
 $ Group                    : chr  "WK" "WK" "WK" "WK" ...
 $ Session                  : Factor w/ 12 levels "AM","AM1","AM2",..: 9 1 9 9 1 9 9 1 1 1 ...
 $ Group.Members.Seen       : num  7 6 8 9 9 6 8 9 4 9 ...
 $ Roving.Males             : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Undyed.Group.Members.Seen: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Non.group.Other          : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ..
```

I don't have an observation for every day, and sometimes have multiple observations for a day. In this particular instance, there is only data in the Group.members.seen column, however in other datasets i do have numbers in roving.males, undyed.group.members.seen, and non.group.other columns.

For this particular dataset, I am only wanting to work with the Date and Group.Members.seen columns, as I only have data in those columns. I've used select to select those columns, then have tried to use mutate, group_by, and summarise to get what I want. However, I think the problem is with the dates. Have also tried aggregate but i don't think that is the best.

```
test <- WK.2013 %>% 
  select(Date, Group.Members.Seen) %>% 
  mutate(mo = Date(format="%m"), mean.num.members = mean(Group.Members.Seen)) %>% 
  group_by(Date(format="%m")) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Group.Members.Seen))
```

Error message is saying it cannot find the function "Date", which is probably the beginning of a long string of problems with that code.

Comment: You're calling `Date` as though it's a function—it's a class, not a function. You might want `format` instead to format your dates, but you'll need to pass your dates to that function (right now you only have `format = "%m"`)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `lubridate` package and round dates to month or year or other units.

```
library(lubridate)

mydate <- today()
```

```
> floor_date(today(),unit = "month")
[1] "2019-07-01"
> floor_date(mydate,unit = "month")
[1] "2019-07-01"
> round_date(mydate,unit = "month")
[1] "2019-08-01"
```

Comment: I managed to use floor_date to assign months to the dates. However, since i want to average (mean()) the numbers from daily observations to make a per month average for each month...it isn't working using group_by and summarise, and i'm assuming that's because the vectors would have different lengths? For example, i have 148 daily observations from the year, which I want to turn into 12 mean monthly observations. Since the dataframe is 148 observations long, i'm assuming R doesn't like that I am trying to insert another column with a vector length of only 12

Comment: Can you ask this question in another post with some examples? I don't think there should be any issues with using `mean()`. If you group by each month and summaries another column, the length of the output in each month should only be one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298332/how-to-group-daily-data-into-months-in-a-dataframe-using-dplyr-part-2

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure if this will work without seeing the actual data but could you try the `apply.monthly` function from the `xts` package?